# Loop over parent ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

I've got a model in my Django project as follows:

```
class Category(models.Model):
   parentCategory = models.ForeignKey(Category,null=True,blank=True)
   category = models.CharField(max_length=255)

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.category
```

I use this to setup category heirachy. Some categories parent category have a parent category that also have a parent category etc. I was wondering how I would loop over this structure in the `__unicode__` method?

Cheers,
Ben

**UPDATE:** 
Below is my structure in my category table:

```
Parent
Parent -> Sub Parent
Parent -> Sub Parent -> Sub Sub Parent
```

The "get_name" function from Aamir Adnan is returning:

```
Parent
Sub Parent -> Sub Sub Parent
Sub Sub Parent
```

I need it to display like this:

```
Parent
Parent -> Sub Parent
Parent -> Sub Parent -> Sub Sub Parent
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Also if you want to have self referential key you can do it `models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is a tree structure, and iterating over all parent elements of a recursive foreign key relationship is unfortunately a very expensive operation; every lookup for the parent will require one database hit, as the other answers demonstrate methods of doing.

What I would suggest you do instead is use a table structure that allows for efficient tree queries.  There are several methods of doing this, but to point you in the right direction I would suggest looking into [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) or [django-treebeard](https://github.com/tabo/django-treebeard).

For example, using django-mptt you could achieve this with the following general structure, which will only result in one additional database hit to query for all ancestors of the target category.

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey


class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    def __unicode__(self):
        ancestors = self.get_ancestors(ascending=False, include_self=True)
        return ' -> '.join(category.name
                           for category in ancestors)
```

Comment: more examples here: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ModifiedPreorderTreeTraversal

Answer (score 3):

How about..

```
   def __unicode__(self):
       str = self.category
       obj = self
       while obj.parentCateogry:
            str += " " + obj.parentCategory.category 
            obj = obj.parentCategory
       return str
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parentCategory = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True,
        related_name="categories")
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_name(self, obj, name=''):
        name += ' - ' + obj.category
        categories = obj.categories.all()
        if categories:
            for category in categories:
                name = self.get_name(category, name)
            return name
        else:
            return name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.get_name(self).strip(' - ').strip()
```

Comment: hmm almost there.. except it's kind of reversed.. if it's a parent it shows childs.. but childs don't show parents. I actually only want it to show parents if it has one.